# how to reshape the Xtrain & Ytrain so that they have the same shape for model training?

Tags: dataframe, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-cleaning

I have a data frame with 11 features, one will be my ytrain the others will be the Xtrain;
ùy problem is that the shape of Xtrain is (2173, 10) or my ytrain shape is (2137,)
how can I fit the two with the same ship to train my model?
ps: I tried transforming them into NumPy arrays 21730 and 2137 but I have the same problem always
any help please or a link for a video similar to my issue.
thanks

Comment: Why do both shapes have to be the same? Normally they are different.

Answer (score 1):

These numbers do not make sense. (2173, 10) is 10 features, not 11. Furthermore (2173*10) is not divisable by 2137, meaning that your data is just **invalid**. You need to have **one label** per data point, so if you have 2137 labels you need 2137 data points, with whatever number of features you like, for example with 11 features this would equal to `2137*11=23507` floats (and not 21730 that you have).

**This is not about reshaping, your data is simply wrong**. This is either caused by wrong loading, or simply by misunderstanding what is inside your data.